# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, correlation, data-science

I've read the other pages on stack exchange on this topic and I still cant figure out why `selectedSub <- subset(corList, (abs(cor) > 0.2 & j == 'Income'))` is returning the error <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).

```
# Url
library(RCurl)
urlfile <- 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data'

x <- getURL(urlfile, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)

#Read csv
adults <- read.csv(textConnection(x), header = F)

head(adults,2)

# Change the header names
names(adults) = c('Age', 'Workclass', 'FinalWeight', 'Eductation',  'EducationNumber',
              'MaritalStatus', 'Occupation', 'Relationship', 'Race', 
              'Sex', 'CapitalGain', 'CapitalLoss', 'HoursWeek', 
              'NativeCountry', 'Income') 

# Change to binary
adults$Income <- ifelse(adults$Income ==' <= 50k', 0,1)

# Change all the factors to numbers
library(caret)
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~.", data = adults)
adultsTrsf <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = adults))
dim(adultsTrsf)
head(adultsTrsf)

## Correlation matrix with p-values.
cor.prob <- function (X, dfr = nrow(X) - 2) {
R <- cor(X, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
above <- row(R) < col(R)
r2 <- R[above]^2
Fstat <- r2 * dfr/(1 - r2)
R[above] <- 1 - pf(Fstat, 1, dfr)
R[row(R) == col(R)] <- NA
R
}

## Use this to dump the cor.prob output to a 4 column matrix
## with row/column indices, correlation, and p-value.
flattenSquareMatrix <- function(m) {
if( (class(m) != "matrix") | (nrow(m) != ncol(m))) stop("Must be a square matrix.")
if(!identical(rownames(m), colnames(m))) stop("Row and column names must be equal.")
ut <- upper.tri(m)
data.frame(i = rownames(m)[row(m)[ut]],
         j = rownames(m)[col(m)[ut]],
         cor=t(m)[ut],
         p=m[ut])
}

##
corMasterList <- flattenSquareMatrix (cor.prob(adultsTrsf))

# Order by absolute correlation value
corList <- corMasterList [order(-abs(corMasterList$cor)),]

##
head(corList)

##
selectedSub <- subset(corList, (abs(cor) > 0.2 & j == 'Income'))

## 
selectedSub
```

Comment: what does `table(corList$j == "Income", abs(corList$cor) > 0.2 )` give you?

Comment: `FALSE TRUE`
`FALSE  5685   93`
`TRUE      0    0`

Comment: So the `TRUE / TRUE` table value is zero?

Comment: yes, true/ true value is is zero

Comment: ... hence why your subset, that requires both of these to be true, has no observations then

Comment: Simple example, `dat = data.frame(x=1, y=1) ; subset(dat, x > 2)` : if no observations meet the subset condition then an empty dataframe is returned

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your response! I'm just having so much trouble finding out _where_ the problem is coming from now I guess. Especially when the source code is available (assumed checked to work). [http://amunategui.github.io/Exploring-Your-Data-Set/#sourcecode]

Comment: Check the parens in the logical statement. They are not correct.

Comment: @Roland l can you point out the error in the subset please as i cant spot it

Comment: Sorry, I can't find it anymore. Maybe I was imagining it.

Comment: @Roland; thanks, thought i had my stupid hat on